# Pickling an object from running process from outside

Tags: python, marshalling, pickle, unmarshalling

Let's suppose I have an object running on a loop. And I want to be able, from another module that is already running to get this object with its current state. 
Let me give you a silly example that illustrates my problem. 
For instance, let's suppose that this is the module that I have running:

**process_a.py**

```
import time
import random

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.random = random.random()

    def get_time(self):
        self.time = time.time()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.get_time()
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print a.random
```

And I want to be able to get this instance `a` from `process_a.py` with its `a.random` and `a.time` attributes to use them in another process. But I can't make any modification to this code. Otherwise I would add a line to `pickle` this instance and the problem would be solved.

Comment: Do you control the launch of `process_a.py`?

Comment: I could. process_a.py could be launched by another process. That's not a constraint.

Comment: Well, theoretically you could run your own file which would "steal" contents of `process_a.py` with `from process_a import *` (or something equivalent) and run it's own version of module-level code, with all necessary hooks. Some trickery may be required to make the code believe it's actually running as top-level module, but nothing undoable. My original idea was more along the lines of `eval`ing it's contents, but I'm not sure that can be done safely.